# R: Combine duplicate entries and conditionally select dates by group

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing hundreds of firms in which employees are grouped by firm `id`. For some firms there are multiple entries for the same `employee`, albeit with different `start` and `stop` dates.

I want to combine or remove the duplicate employee entries, while keeping both the earlier of the two start dates and later of the two end dates. My dataset looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  employee = c("culver", "maguire", "florenzano","cretu", "tran", "ryman",
  "menezes", "dancause", "schumaker", "tyler", "cretu", "tran", "menezes"),
  started = structure(c(15014, 15014, 15014, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15706, 15492, 15706), class = "Date"),
  ended = structure(c(18157, 15126, 15126, 15949, 15949, 15461, 15705, 15461, 15461, 15584, 18157,
  15706, 15876), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", "employee", "started","ended"))
```

You can see that Firm 2 has duplicate entries for Cretu, Tran, and Menezes. The final dataset should look like this:

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  employee = c("culver", "maguire", "florenzano","cretu", "tran", "ryman",
  "menezes", "dancause", "schumaker", "tyler"),
  started = structure(c(15014, 15014, 15014, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279, 15279), class = "Date"),
  ended = structure(c(18157, 15126, 15126, 18157, 15949, 15461, 15876, 15461, 15461, 15584), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", "employee", "started","ended"))
```

I've tried a number of solutions involving `mutate`, `which.min` and `which.max` with no success. There should be a tidy solution available here but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you just need to replace duplicates with `NA`? It's not very clear from your description(at least to me) what transformation you're doing.

Comment: Ideally the solution would combine the duplicate employee entries, selecting the earlier of the two start dates and later of the two end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id, employee) %>% 
  summarise(started = min(started), ended = max(ended)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This works great for identifying the correct dates, except that I have a number of other columns in the dataset that I excluded from the example, and using `summarize` cuts them out of the final data frame. That's on me for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: @gwcd7p I based my solution on what you provided. Include more data to get help with the problem

Comment: There are 14 other columns containing the firm's name, employee's title, the founding and closing dates of the firm, and financial metrics that don't vary by employee. I'd like to keep all of them in the final panel.

Comment: If all those other columns are the same for each row in a given group, you could replace summarise in the code above with mutate, then add a `%>% summarise_all(first)` step after (but before ungroup).

Answer (score 0):

That did it. The initial code from @slava-kohut with @IceCreamToucan's suggestion returned the correct results. Thank you both for the help.